# How to prevent Armour Stand equipment and passengers from turning black when entering a block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm in Java 1.14.4 and I'm trying to create a gate out of iron bars, that slides open and closed, smoothly.

I have `/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["gate"],NoGravity:1b,Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:falling_block",NoGravity:1b,BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:iron_bars",Properties:{east:"true",west:"true"}},Time:-2147483648,DropItem:0b}]}`Which is a falling block iron bar riding an armour stand.

I'm using `execute as @e[tag=gate] at @s run tp @s ~ ~0.053 ~` to teleport the armour stand up and down to create a sliding gate.  However, the issue is that when the armour stand goes into a block, the iron bar will turn black.

[image]

I've tried setting both the armour stand and falling block on fire so the lightning remains bright with `execute as @e[type=falling_block] run data modify entity @s Fire set value 2000` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Entities always have the light level of the block they're in.

You could alternatively use minecarts with a DisplayTile and a huge offset, that way you can put them into a well lit room way lower. But then the blocks are slightly smaller than a full block, maxing that you need to use more for the same width and that it's visible that you're not using real blocks.

Comment: You could also try a big stack of things riding things riding things, but I don't think that helps.

Comment: After hearing that entities have the light lvl of whatever block they are in I decided to have the gate slide into a transparent block, in my case ice, which was a workaround to that.